# In Xcode, is there a place where font size is stored?

Tags: xcode, variables, fonts, size, int

In xCode i want to store the font size of a label in an int variable. Where can i find this if it's there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried the font property ?

```
myLabel.font.pointSize
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the font using Interface Builder (IB) of Xcode.  The font setting is on the Attributes Inspector.

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Comment: I think he was asking for access to the font size. And where it is stored. Setting something in interface builder is a trivial task. and sometimes its not as simple to find in the actual code.